# Saving mongodb on volume using docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

In my project I have few container managed by docker-compose. I would like to store data from mongoDB on persistent volume. MongoDB seems to store data in /data/db but files are not transferred to my host file system and they disappear after rebuilding container.

Here is my docker-compose config file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes: 
      - "db-data:/data/db"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - elk

  web: 
    build: ./app
    environment:
      - WAIT_COMMAND=1
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on: 
      - db


networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tries to use what is called 'named volumes' that are stored inside docker itself. To mount volume to your file system just write path and not volume name.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3

```
version: '2'

services:

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes: 
      - /data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - elk

  web: 
    build: ./app
    environment:
      - WAIT_COMMAND=1
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on: 
      - db


networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: i get permission denied when trying to look at the volume.

Comment: @chovy if it is still relevant... https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives